# update using order by in subquery to retrieve first row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying, using Oracle 11g, to update one column of one table from the first row of a set of responses. I have one table containing the consumptions of a specific product at a specific date (cb_consumption), and one other table with the changing prices of all products for almost every day - measured in time elapsed - (cb_price). I try to get the price at the nearest date of the consumption date.
If I do :

```
update cb_consumption t1 
set price = (select t2.price 
             from (select t2.price 
                   from cb_price t2 
                   where t2.id_product = t1.id_product 
                   order by abs(t2.elapsed_time - t1.elapsed_time) asc) 
             where rownum < 2);
```

I get "invalid identifier" error (ORA-00904). It seems identifiers don't follow in sub-subqueries.
And if I do :

```
update cb_consumption t1 
set price = (select t2.price 
             from cb_price t2 
             where t2.id_product = t1.id_product 
             and rownum < 2
             order by abs(t2.elapsed_time - t1.elapsed_time) asc);
```

I get "missing right parenthesis" error (ORA-00907). It seems impossible to use "order by" in subqueries.

I don't see solutions. If you have ideas. Thank you by advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way!  Using `keep`:

```
update cb_consumption c
    set price = (select max(p.price) keep (dense_rank first order by abs(p.elapsed_time - c.elapsed_time))
                 from cb_price p
                 where p.id_product = c.id_product 
                );
```

Oracle only recognizes outer aliases in the immediate subquery.  It is not recognized at lower levels of nesting.

Answer (score 0):

if you get error (ORA-00904), you need to recheck the object's name (tables, columns). if the name doesn't match (upper/lower case), then it'll throw this error. because if you put the name without a quotes, it'll be case sensitive. To ignore it, you have to put the object name inside a quotes.

As of Error  (ORA-00907) is because you used ORDER BY clause inside a subquery, which is supported in Oracle only if you put your `ORDER BY` into a view select and include `rownum = 1` in your `WHERE` clause. So, your `UPDATE` should be like this:

```
UPDATE CB_CONSUMPTION
SET 
    PRICE = (
    SELECT PriceTotal 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            T2.PRICE AS PriceTotal
        FROM 
            CB_PRICE T2
        INNER JOIN CB_CONSUMPTION T1 ON T1.ID_PRODUCT = T2.ID_PRODUCT 
        ORDER BY 
            ABS(T2.ELAPSED_TIME - T1.ELAPSED_TIME) ASC
    )

    WHERE 
        ROWNUM = 1

    );
```

Comment: This query doesnt't work, ORA-00904: "T1"."ELAPSED_TIME": invalid identifier

Comment: @krokodilko could you please post both tables schema?

Comment: please examine this fillde: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=017dff2c0161c10241a0f89082124a04, your update doesn't work due to : `ORA-00904: "T1"."ELAPSED_TIME": invalid identifier`

Comment: Check it out : http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=336f551b8e73269a29a97eae22ffe8e8

Comment: @krokodilko sorry, forgot to tag your name, check the link upstairs ^^.

Comment: now the query in DBFiddle works, but UPDATE in the answer still does not work because it's different from dbfiddle. I vote down your answer because it is still incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The first example incorrectly refers to the `price` column of an unnamed inline view as `t2.price`. You need to either remove `t2.` or name the inline view:

```
update cb_consumption t1 
set price = (select price  -- not t2.price
             from (select t2.price 
                   from cb_price t2 
                   where t2.id_product = t1.id_product 
                   order by abs(t2.elapsed_time - t1.elapsed_time) asc) 
             where rownum < 2);

update cb_consumption t1 
set price = (select t3.price 
             from (select t2.price 
                   from cb_price t2 
                   where t2.id_product = t1.id_product 
                   order by abs(t2.elapsed_time - t1.elapsed_time) asc) t3
             where rownum < 2);
```

Your second example fails because `order by` is not allowed in a single-row subquery, such as one in an `update` or `select (select)`. You can use `order by` in other subqueries.

In Oracle 12.1 it becomes valid if you include a [row limiting clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1):

```
update cb_consumption t1 
set    price =
       ( select t2.price 
         from   cb_price t2 
         where  t2.id_product = t1.id_product 
         order by abs(t2.elapsed_time - t1.elapsed_time) asc
         fetch first row only );
```